# Kotlin line break in sums — result depends on operator placement

Tags: kotlin, syntax, operators

today I've encountered a strange behaviour in Kotlin that I cannot explain. Given the following code:

```
data class Data(
    val v1: Int,
    val v2: Int,
    val v3: Int)

fun main() {

    val d = Data(1,1,1)

    val sum1 = d.v1 + d.v2 + d.v3
    println("Oneliner: $sum1") // prints: Oneliner: 3

    val sum2 = d.v1 
        + d.v2 
        + d.v3
    println("OperatorFirst: $sum2") // prints: OperatorFirst: 1

    val sum3 = d.v1 + 
        d.v2 + 
        d.v3
    println("OperatorLast: $sum3") // prints: OperatorLast: 3

}
```

(Testable at: https://pl.kotl.in/gMjif_6FO)

Now it seems to depend on where you place the `+` operator to get the correct result of 3. However, the IDE doesn't show that anything might be wrong with the second version and i couldn't find any information of why this case would behave differently.

A question on the software engineering space also says that several coding guidelines suggest to put the operator at the beginning of the line: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93670/line-break-before-after-operator

Also, the only explanation I could find for this behaviour is that the `+` at the line beginnings is interpreted as a unary plus operator. https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators#unary
However, even this makes no sense to me on a `val`

Comment: that's ugly... at least I hoped that it shows a "this expression is unused" or similar hint in the IDE... regarding "makes no sense": you can also put unused strings, objects, etc. on a single line... and yes... that would make no sense too... (regardless of having a `val` or not ;-)) ... at least for `String`, `Number`, etc. (without `unaryPlus`) you would get such a unused-expression-hint... so I would probably file a bug, if there isn't such already, that such a hint or a warning is presented... I think no one wants a `+Number` (or also `-Number`) which is nowhere used...

Comment: Seems to be less dangerous to use the `plus` method: `val sum4 = d.v1.plus(d.v2).plus(d.v3)`...

Comment: @deHaar while correct, `1 + 2` is easier to write and read than `1.plus(2)`, even more so, the more variables and numbers come into play... Also note, that writing `1 + 3 * 2` is not the same as `1.plus(3).times(2)`... so you have to apply the operator precedence rules by yourself... using an IDE to transform the calculation may put you the required parentheses on the right place...

Comment: @Roland sure... I was just adding a possibility of circumventing the issue with the operator placement. Should be fixed anyway if the behaviour is not desired.

Comment: that's good! ... I justed wanted to point out that precendence rules may need to be applied via parentheses... I really think having unused `+Number` or `-Number` should be a warning... as long as those are the standard implementations... (because for DSLs those might be used differently... but that's also rather some kind of workaround)

Answer (score 5):

That's the price you pay for optional semicolons. Andrey Breslav said in one of his lectures that it is intended behavior. Binary operators like + or * should be placed on the top line, not the bottom line. If you want to place them on bottom line, use parentheses:

```
val sum = (1
        + 1 
        + 1)
println(sum) // prints: 3
```

Comment: Ahh right, using the parentheses there would work. And yes, in languages with a non-optional semicolon to end a command this wouldn't happen.

However, even if intended behaviour I'm not sure whether there should be at least a warning in the common IDEs as this is quite error-prone. And it's something even code reviewers will hardly find.