# Kotlin: Why isn't '+ a + b' reported as a syntax error?

Tags: kotlin

I just diagnosed a silly bug that came down to a line break mid expression:

```
 val total = anObject.oneLongVariableName + anObject.secondLongVariableName
           + anObject.thirdLongVariableName + anObject.fourthLongVariableName
```

This looks valid and compiles, but the third and fourth variables are not added to the total.

This works correctly.

```
 val total = anObject.oneLongVariableName + anObject.secondLongVariableName +
             anObject.thirdLongVariableName + anObject.fourthLongVariableName
```

and this is a syntax error:

```
 val product = anObject.oneLongVariableName * anObject.secondLongVariableName
             * anObject.thirdLongVariableName * anObject.fourthLongVariableName
```

but + and - are "allowed" and seemingly discarded by the parser.

Comment: because it considers them 2 different operation (thus the second line is not added to the total)... and `+a+b` is valid because is `(+a)+b` and `+` can be an unitary operator such as `-a`... where instead `*` cannot be interpreted as unitary... the middle one works because that trailing `+` is telling kotlin that there is something more to add, and it's going to look for it in the next line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin line break in sums — result depends on operator placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712664/kotlin-line-break-in-sums-result-depends-on-operator-placement)

Comment: Indeed - but the lack of warning is annoying. 

`1+2` or `+1+2` gives no warning but `+1` gives `Unused unary operator`. It feels like the compiler should be able to spot the problem.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA shows the second line highlighted in yellow and says "Unused unary operator".

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't show any warning for me in the `+ 1 + 2` or `1 + 2` cases.

Comment: IntelliJ shows "Unused unary operator" if you put `+ 2` on a line of its own.

Comment: Since kotlin provides [operator overload](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#unary-prefix-operators) it could be useful to have `+a` on a line independent of anything else. It would be a horrible practice, but maybe

Comment: @matt it's actually done in some DSLs, not necessarily a bad thing

Comment: @JasonChown what's the type of your variables?

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the [unaryPlus](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#unary-prefix-operators) operator.

The expression `+something` is valid if `something` is of a type that defines the `operator fun unaryPlus`.

On the other hand, there no unary `*` operator, only the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs), and it's only valid in specific places of the code (when calling a function with a `vararg` argument and passing an array to it).

Comment: It isn't just the unary operator. The expression `a+b` will be silently discarded by the parser.

Comment: @JasonChown it's not silently discarded: if `a` and `b` were _properties_, they would be invoked (`getA()` and `getB()`) including any side-effects they may have.

Comment: I'd rather expect the result of the expression `a+b` to be computed and discarded. Maybe, but that's an optimizer question, it could be discarded if it can be proven to be free of any side effects. That's much later than during parsing though, @JasonChown. ;)

Comment: I meant the result is silently discarded.  I think it should be a warning.

Comment: @JasonChown certain other jvm based languages agree and make it a compiler error even.